# IntegrityError at /registerdoctor.html NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.first_name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I created a Doctor model having a OneToOneField with the Django User model. When I hit the 'Sign Up' button I get an Integrity Error :

> "IntegrityError at /registerdoctor.html NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   auth_user.first_name"

Can someone tell me how do I can fix the error i.e. what changes I should make and where?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Doctor(models.Model):
    doctor = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #additional
    exp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    phone_no = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.doctor.username
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,auth
from django.contrib import messages
from app1.models import Doctor

def HomePage(request):
    return render(request,'homepage.html')

def RegisterUser(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        first_name = request.POST["fname"]
        last_name = request.POST["lname"]
        email_id = request.POST["mail"]
        password1 = request.POST["pass1"]
        password2 = request.POST["pass2"]
        username = request.POST["username"]

        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email_id).exists():
                messages.info(request,"This Email ID is already Registered!")
                return redirect("registeruser.html")
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                    messages.info(request,"Username taken!")
                    return redirect("registeruser.html")
                else:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,
                                                    email=email_id,password=password1,username=username)
                    user.save()
                    return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request,"Passwords Not Matching!")
            return redirect("registeruser.html")
        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render(request,'registeruser.html')

def RegisterDoctor(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name = request.POST.get("finame")
        last_name = request.POST.get("laname")
        email_id = request.POST.get("emailid")
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        phone = request.POST.get("phno")
        exp = request.POST.get("doc_exp")
        password1 = request.POST.get("userpassword")
        password2 = request.POST.get("conpassword")

        if password1==password2:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email_id).exists():
                messages.info(request,"This Email ID is already Registered!")
                return redirect("registerdoctor.html")
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                    messages.info(request,"Username taken!")
                    return redirect("registerdoctor.html")
                else:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,  email=email_id, password=password1, username=username)
                    doctor = Doctor.objects.create(experience=exp, phone_no=phone_no, user=user)
                    doctor.save()
                    return redirect("/")
        else:
            messages.info(request,"Passwords Not Matching!")
            return redirect("registerdoctor.html")
        return redirect("/")

    else:
        return render(request,'registerdoctor.html')
```

**registerdoctor.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content%}

{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app1/doctor_signup.css' %}">
<br>
  <div class="center-it">
  <h4 class="display-4"> Doctor's Sign Up Page: <h4>
    <br>
    <br>
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <label for="finame">
  <input type="text" align = "center" id = "fname" name="" placeholder=" First Name " required>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="laname">
  <input type="text" align ="center"  id ="lname" name="" placeholder=" Last Name" required>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="emailid">
    <input id="emailid" align="center" type="email" name="" placeholder=" Email address" required></br>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="username">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
  </label>
  <br>
  <label for="phno">
    <input id ="phno" type="tel" name="" placeholder=" Phone No">
  </label>
  <br>
  <label align ="centre" for ="doc_exp">
  Years of Experience in  Psychology
  <select name="Years" id="doc_exp" required>
    <option value="Experienced">10+</option>
    <option value="Amateur">5+</option>
    <option value="Beginner">2+</option>
  </select>
</label>
<br>
  <label for="userpassword">
  <input type="password" id ="userpassword" name="" placeholder=" Password" required></br>
</label>
  <br>
  <label for="conpassword">
  <input type="password" id = "conpassword" name="" placeholder=" Confirm Password" required>
  </label>
  <hr class="my-4">

  <input type="Submit" value="Sign Up">
    <div class="error">
      {% for message in messages %}
      <h3>{{message}}</h3>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/registerdoctor.html

Django Version: 2.2.6
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app1']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.first_name) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\anwes\OneDrive\Desktop\Zen Django\Zen\Zen\views.py" in RegisterDoctor
  60.                     user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name,  email=email_id, password=password1, username=username)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in create_user
  151.         return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in _create_user
  145.         user.save(using=self._db)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in save
  66.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "D:\Pycharm Projects\Django Course\MyEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  383.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /registerdoctor.html
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.first_name
```

Comment: Don't do any of this. Use a ModelForm.

Answer (score 0):

in RegisterDoctor method, do check if 'user' is None before create doctor.

i think your 'user' is a None object.